# How to rename x-axis labels in gam plot in R?

Tags: r, visualization, gam, mgcv

I fitted the model using the following code

```
mod1 <- gam(severity ~  s(mean_rh, k = 8) + s(mean_temp, k = 10) + s(mean_ws, k =7) + s(avg_daily_rain, k = 7), family = betar(),  data = dat_seasonal)
```

Here is the code used in producing plot

```
plot(mod1, pages = 1, all.terms = TRUE, rug = TRUE, residuals = TRUE, pch = 1, cex = 1, shade = TRUE, seWithMean = TRUE, shift = coef(mod1)[1])
```

I wanted to rename x-axis labels by renaming column names in the original data frame, using new name  = old syntax, `Mean temperature` = mean_temp,
`Mean wind speed` = mean_ws,
`Mean relative humidity` = mean_rh,
`Mean rain per rainy day` = avg_daily_rain

Here is my code

```
names(dat_seasonal) <- c("disease_severity", "Mean relative humidity", "Mean temperature", "Mean wind speed", "Mean rain per rainy day")

mod1 <- gam(disease_severity ~  s(`Mean relative humidity`, k = 8) + s(`Mean temperature`, k = 10) + s(`Mean wind speed`, k =7) + s(`Mean rain per rainy day`, k = 7), family = betar(),  data = dat_seasonal_gam)

summary(mod1)


plot(mod1, pages = 1, all.terms = TRUE, rug = TRUE, residuals = TRUE, pch = 1, cex = 1, shade = TRUE, seWithMean = TRUE, shift = coef(mod1)[1])
```

I am getting the following error message

```
Error in str2lang(termtext) : <text>:1:6: unexpected symbol
1: Mean relative
         ^
```

Apparently, the error message suggests that there should not be any spaces in the new names. Any leads on how to fix this? Thanks

NOTE:
I can rename a single term using the following code, but there is no way rename all predictors at once.

```
plot(mod1, select = 4, xlab = "Mean rain per rainy day (mm)", rug = TRUE, residuals = TRUE, pch = 1, cex = 1, shade = TRUE, seWithMean = TRUE, shift = coef(mod1)[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using `gratia` package to rename individual figures and then combine them using `patchwork` package.

```
p1 <- draw(mod1, select = "s(mean_rh)") +
      labs(x= "Mean relative humidity (%)", title = "")

p2 <- draw(mod1, select = "s(mean_temp)") +
   labs(x= "Mean temperature (°C)", title = "") 

p3 <- draw(mod1, select = "s(mean_ws)") +
  labs(x= "Mean wind speed (m/s)", title = "") 

p4 <- draw(mod1, select = "s(avg_daily_rain)") +
  labs(x= "Mean rain per rainy day (mm)", title = "") 

p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + plot_layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```